# How to theme the heading in a view with grouped fields

Tags: views, theming, entities

I have a view of a list of nodes, the nodes are being displayed as fields, in an html list. I'm grouping by two fields, (type and category) so that my view displays like this

Type A
    Catagory A
        Node1
        Node2
    Catagory B
        Node3
        Node4

The view prints both groupings, and now I'm trying to customize the css of both the type and category titles. Unfortunately when I try to alter the field template (by creating a new one) I can't seem to add the code in the right place. When I alter my field template to this.

```
<div class="menu-category">
   <?php print $output; ?>
</div>
```

it prints that div within the  tag and therefor does not work.

```
    <div class="view-grouping-content">
<h3>

   My Category


</h3>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the result of each field, do this steps for the two fields:

1. In the views edit page, click on the field (type) then check "rewrite result".
2. using replacement patterns you can print the field value between `H3` tag like this:

```
<h3 class="some-class">[field_type]</h3>
```

3. click save.

After That you have to write CSS style in `style.css` file as you like.

Comment: I tried something similar, it works for the actual field (ie if the field is being displayed). But I am hiding the field from display, and only showing the heading (the heading it is grouped by). For some reason , the "rewrite result" does not effect the grouped title

Comment: In the head of views you can add text area field, then you can use Replacement pattern to print it between H3 tags

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding a couple of views templates.

If you are only grouping by one field then you would override it in the display template, which in your case is `views-view-list.tpl.php`.

The part that you want to modify is:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)) : ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you are grouping by 2 or more fields then the last of those is handled as above.
The others are handled by overriding the `views-view-grouping.tpl.php` template.
The part you want to modify is:

```
<div class="view-grouping-header"><?php print $title; ?></div>
```